# How to specify java script files required by an angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a way to specify required js files by an angular app. So that, we don't need to include an array of  tag for all the files which may be required by some ng-app. The main idea behind this requirement is - we might not need to load all the resources on the browser at once. Which ever ng-app gets loaded onto the screen, will fetch its dependencies on its own from the server. Is there any existing way within angularJS to achieve this goal..?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called lazy loading, I think, and it can be achieved with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Here's a [discussion on implementing lazy loading in AngularJS with RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134023/lazy-loading-angularjs-modules-with-requirejs).