# Structuring AngularJS code using RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm looking at managing my AngularJS code using RequireJS and have come up with the following pattern:

```
"use strict";

(function () {

    var moduleName = "module.name";

    define(
        [
            'angular'
        ],
        function (
            ng
        ) {

            ng.module(moduleName, []);

            return moduleName;

        }
    );

})();
```

I guess the general idea is that whenever my module/controller/etc... is included, rather than returning the object itself, it binds it's name into Angular and then returns that handle to the caller.

One question I have - Would it be a better idea to return the array parameter I'm passing to `ng.module` and then eliminate the call, allowing the "includer" of this module to decide what name to bind to?

Are there any other pitfalls or recommendations for designing nicely encapsulated AngularJS+RequireJS modules that could be applied to this pattern?  Anything I should watch out for to avoid hardship or confusion in the future?

Comment: Have tried your code to see if it is working after angular.bootstrap?  I am pretty sure that modules created using your pattern after bootstrap cannot be injected into your app.  Take a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134023/lazy-loading-angularjs-modules-with-requirejs

Comment: Actually that same pattern is the one I use to create AngularJS apps. Checkout the example code at my Github: http://github.com/leog/epsilon