# AngularJS: lazy loading controllers and content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lazy-loading, controllers

In this simplified scenario, I have two files: index.htm, lazy.htm.

index.htm:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('embed',function($scope){
    $scope.embed = 'Embedded Controller';
});                  
<div ng-controller="embed">{{embed}}</div>    
<div ng-include="'lazy.htm'"></div>
```

lazy.htm

```
myApp.controller('lazy',function($scope){
    $scope.lazy = 'Lazy Controller';
});
<div ng-controller="lazy">
    {{lazy}}
</div>
```

The result is an error: "Argument 'lazy' is not a function, got undefined"

Using a function instead

lazy.htm

```
function lazy($scope) {
    $scope.lazy = 'Lazy Controller';
}
<div ng-controller="lazy">
    {{lazy}}
</div>
```

This works until version 1.3 beta 14. In beta 15 was removed the global controller functions: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8296

So now, what is the better way to get angularized contents of lazy.htm dynamically?

**UPDATE:**

In this article (http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs) I found another possible solution. The $controllerProvider allow us to register new controllers after angular bootstrap. Works like a charm. Tested in **v1.3.0-beta.18**

index.htm:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('embed',function($scope){
    $scope.embed = 'Embedded Controller';
})
.config(function($controllerProvider) {
    myApp.cp = $controllerProvider;
});

<div ng-controller="embed">{{embed}}</div>    
<div ng-include="'lazy.htm'"></div>
```

lazy.htm

```
myApp.cp.register('lazy',function($scope){
    $scope.lazy = 'Lazy Controller';
});
<div ng-controller="lazy">
    {{lazy}}
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Two other alternatives that works are:

lazy.htm

```
_app = $('[ng-app]').scope();    
_app.lazy = function($scope) {
    $scope.lazy = 'Lazy Controller';
};
```

OR

```
var $rootScope = $('[ng-app]').injector().get('$rootScope');        
$rootScope.lazy = function($scope) {
    $scope.lazy = 'Lazy Controller';
};
```

But I believe these last two examples should not be used in production.

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Comment: This question gave me one of the most beautiful moments in my life. Through simple usage of `$controllerProvider`, now I can have *self-contained* piece of client-side codes. That is, HTML + JS in one file.

Comment: You can use requireJs and ocLazyload to load the files and inject modules dynamically.. Refer the article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1039826/Angularjs-Lazy-loading-with-Requirejs-and-OcLazylo

Comment: Try ocLazyload example app here http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-lazy-load-modules-controllers-angularjs/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also use the jquery with the resolve the $routeProvider

app.js

```
/* Module Creation */
var app = angular.module ('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider){

/*Creating a more synthesized form of service of $ controllerProvider.register*/
app.registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;

function loadScript(path) {
  var result = $.Deferred(),
  script = document.createElement("script");
  script.async = "async";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = path;
  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function (_, isAbort) {
      if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) {
         if (isAbort)
             result.reject();
         else
            result.resolve();
    }
  };
  script.onerror = function () { result.reject(); };
  document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
  return result.promise();
}

function loader(arrayName){

    return {
      load: function($q){
                var deferred = $q.defer(),
                map = arrayName.map(function(name) {
                    return loadScript('js/controllers/'+name+".js");
                });

                $q.all(map).then(function(r){
                    deferred.resolve();
                });

                return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}

$routeProvider  
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/foo.html',
        resolve: loader(['foo'])
    })
    .when('/bar',{
        templateUrl: 'views/bar.html',
        controller: 'BarCtrl',
        resolve: loader(['bar'])
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: document.location.pathname
    });
}]);
```

/views/foo.html

```
<section ng-controller='FooCtrl'>
    {{text}}
</section>
```

js/controllers/foo.js

```
/*Here we use the synthesized version of $controllerProvider.register 
to register the controller in view*/
app.registerCtrl('FooCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.text = 'Test';
});
```

/views/bar.html

```
<section>
    {{text2}}
</section>
```

js/controllers/bar.js

```
app.registerCtrl('BarCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.text2 = 'Test';
});
```

Comment: This does not work always - sometimes getScript executes after the view is rendered. /*Here is the magic, the jquery getScript will take the script in the directory that I want before rendering the view*/

Comment: Hi, thanks for watching, I made a new version, try now

Comment: It will also fail on any modern build system.

Comment: This is working fine.. But Is there any way so that duplicate script can be avoided as it will add every time. Not checking if already added.

Comment: You can cache the file or as it is recommended that this file be very small, something in kb, if by chance you have a second download it should not affect performance

Answer (score 4):

You can have pure AngularJS lazy loading.

Create "LazyService":

```
var ng = angular.module('app');

ng.factory('lazyService', [ '$http', function($http) {
    var jsPath = 'js/${ name }.js';
    var promisesCache = {};

    return {
        loadScript: function(name) {
            var path = jsPath.replace('${ name }', name);
            var promise = promisesCache[name];
            if (!promise) {
                promise = $http.get(path);
                promisesCache[name] = promise;

                return promise.then(function(result) {
                    eval(result.data);
                    console.info('Loaded: ' + path);
                });
            }

            return promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then, define your config:

```
var ng = angular.module('app', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

ng.config([ '$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$provide', function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $provide) {
    // Lazy loading
    ng.lazy = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
        //directive: $compileProvider.directive,
        //filter: $filterProvider.register,
        factory: $provide.factory,
        service: $provide.service
    }

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
    })
    .when('/vendor', {
        templateUrl: 'view/vendor.html',
        resolve: {
            svc: [ 'lazyService', function(lazyService) {
                return lazyService.loadScript('services/vendor');
            }],
            ctrl: [ 'lazyService', function(lazyService) {
                return lazyService.loadScript('controllers/vendor');
            }]
        }
    });
. . .
```

On "js/services/vendor.js", create service as:

```
var ng = angular.module('app');
ng.lazy.service('vendorService', [ function() {
. . .
```

On "js/controllers/vendor.js", create controller as:

```
var ng = angular.module('app');
ng.lazy.controller('vendorController', [ function() {
. . .
```

The "resolve" property on when defines which promises should be resolved before route loads.

Comment: I have been used your solution but now I want to cancel requests when route change, I use resource for my requests, would you please help me, tnx

Comment: This is quite hacky, and if we are using babel and typescript, we can't put it in angular.module('app'), sadly, because it seems angularJS 1.8.x rebuilding the class and left out the `.lazy`, in the end I use window.lazy, so the lazy object available on everywhere. Well I still tinkering to make it works...

Answer (score 3):

////JConfig file--------

```
window.angularApp.config(function ($routeProvider,$controllerProvider,$compileProvider,$provide, azMessages) {

$routeProvider.when('/login', {
             resolve: {
                 load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                     var deferred = $q.defer();
                     require([

                         //load required Js file here

                ], function () {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });
                     return deferred.promise;
                 } ]
             }
         });


  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

    window.angularApp.components = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
        service: $provide.service,
        directive: $compileProvider.directive
    }
```

//contoller declaration

```
angularApp.components.controller('DiscussionController',[function(){

}]);
```

Comment: `require` only takes 1 argument.

Answer (score 2):

At first I utilized André Betiolo's answer. However, it does not always work becasue the ajax loading is non-blocking causing the view to sometimes request the controller prior to the script being loaded.

As a solution i forced the function not to return until all scripts successfully loaded. This is kind of hackish but makes sure the loads are successful prior to completing the resolve. It also allows for loading of multiple controllers.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module ('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider){

    /*Creating a more synthesized form of service of $ controllerProvider.register*/
    app.registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;

    //jquery to dynamically include controllers as needed
    function controllers(controllers){
        var numLoaded = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
            $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
            $.getScript('js/controllers/' + controllers[i] + '.js').success(function(){
                numLoaded++;
                if (numLoaded == controllers.length) {
                    return true; //only return after all scripts are loaded, this is blocking, and will fail if all scripts aren't loaded.
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/foo.html',
            resolve: {
                load: function () {
                    controllers(['foo'])
                }
            }
        })
        .when('/bar',{
            templateUrl: 'views/bar.html',
            controller: 'BarCtrl',
            resolve: {
                load: function () {
                    controllers(['bar','foo']) //you can load multiple controller files
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: document.location.pathname
        });
}]);
```

/views/foo.html

```
<section ng-controller='FooCtrl'>
    {{text}}
</section>
```

/views/bar.html

```
<section ng-controller='BarCtrl'>
    {{text2}}
</section>
<section ng-controller='FooCtrl'>
    {{text}}
</section>
```

/controllers/bar.js

```
app.registerCtrl('BarCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.text2 = 'Test';
});
```

Comment: I made a new version, try now

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you are asking is to instead use a directive and tie the controller and template together that way so its bound at the appropriate time. Currently, the binding it not happening in `lazy.htm` at the right time unless you declare a global function as you've shown in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally - Angular will force you to separate HTML and JS as in newer versions this may be enforced more often.

You may have to use requireJS 
http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/09/30/requirejs-angularjs-dependency-injection/

For the sake of trick can you try

```
ng-controller-controller="'lazy'"
```

or

In HTML

ng-controller-controller="myObject.controller"

Somewhere inject

```
$scope.myObject.controller = $controller('lazy', {$scope: $scope})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ARI [plugin](https://github.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector) for Angular JS. It helps you to lazy load the controller scripts on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use Directives to load your controller!

A example here:

https://gist.github.com/raphaelluchini/53d08ed1331e47aa6a87

Answer (score 0):

I am sending you sample code. It is working fine for me. So please check this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

/* Module Creation */
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider) {

app.register = {
    controller: $controllerProvider.register,
    //directive: $compileProvider.directive,
    //filter: $filterProvider.register,
    //factory: $provide.factory,
    //service: $provide.service
};


//    so I keep a reference from when I ran my module config
function registerController(moduleName, controllerName) {
    // Here I cannot get the controller function directly so I
    // need to loop through the module's _invokeQueue to get it
    var queue = angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue;
    for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        var call = queue[i];
        if (call[0] == "$controllerProvider" &&
           call[1] == "register" &&
           call[2][0] == controllerName) {
            app.register.controller(controllerName, call[2][1]);
        }
    }
}


var tt = {
    loadScript:
function (path) {
    var result = $.Deferred(),
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = "async";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = path;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function (_, isAbort) {
        if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) {
            if (isAbort)
                result.reject();
            else {
                result.resolve();
            }
        }
    };
    script.onerror = function () { result.reject(); };
    document.querySelector(".shubham").appendChild(script);
    return result.promise();
}
}

function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.querySelector(".shubham");
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}


function loader(arrayName) {
    return {
        load: function ($q) {
            stripScripts(''); // This Function Remove javascript from Local
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            map = arrayName.map(function (obj) {
                return tt.loadScript(obj.path)
                .then(function () {
                    registerController(obj.module, obj.controller);
                })
            });

            $q.all(map).then(function (r) {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
};



$routeProvider
    .when('/first', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/foo.html',
        resolve: loader([{ controller: 'FirstController', path: '/MyScripts/FirstController.js', module: 'app' },
            { controller: 'SecondController', path: '/MyScripts/SecondController.js', module: 'app' }])
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/bar.html',
        resolve: loader([{ controller: 'SecondController', path: '/MyScripts/SecondController.js', module: 'app' },
        { controller: 'A', path: '/MyScripts/anotherModuleController.js', module: 'myapp' }])
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: document.location.pathname
        });
}])
```

And in HTML Page:

```
<body ng-app="app">

<div class="container example">
    <!--ng-controller="testController"-->

    <h3>Hello</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#/first">First Page </a></td>
            <td><a href="#/second">Second Page</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>




        <div id="ng-view" class="wrapper_inside" ng-view>
        </div>
    <div class="shubham">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank U