# How lazy load js scripts synchronously?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to find a **tool** or a **.js** lib to lazy load my scripts on demand of the routes/urls'.

Basically, I want to:

```
state = {
  state: 'widgets',
  config: {
     url: '/',
     templateUrl: 'modules/widgets/templates/widgets.template.html',
     resolve: {
         // load the .js  somehow
     }          
}
$stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
```

have anyone already done that? or is there a stand for lazy load **.js** files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not exactly what you need, but yes, you can use `$controllerProvider`.
you can find a very nice article here that explains lazy loading in angular - http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

check this out - [AngularJS: lazy loading controllers and content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168593/angularjs-lazy-loading-controllers-and-content)
and the lazy load library 
https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Comment: Thanks! It's a good start!

Answer (score 1):

You can use UI-Router Extras Future States  https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future

There is a yeoman generator: https://github.com/matoilic/generator-angular-lazy which can get you started quickly with ocLazyLoad + Future States