# Defining script and controller in route

Tags: angularjs

Currently I add my controllers in `index.html` with just a normal `script` tag like so

```
<script src="js/controllers/admin/languages.js"></script>
```

I was wondering if it's possible to to tell the state that I want to include this script so that I don't have to add all my controller script in the index.

```
.state('admin.languages', {
    url: '/languages',
    templateUrl: 'views/admin/languages.html'
})
```

This is what my state looks like now.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like [lazy loading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load) ? Do you intend to use Angular 1.x or Angular 2 and above ?

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168593/angularjs-lazy-loading-controllers-and-content

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a `reslove` that handles dynamically loading the script containing the target controller and resolve the promise once the load is complete :

```
.state('admin.languages', {
url: '/languages',
templateUrl: 'views/admin/languages.html',
resolve: resolveController('js/controllers/admin/languages.js')
})
```