# can i put angularjs controller into function then load it by button onclick event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i dont want to load controller when page is load.i want to load it after click the button.
Here is my code, help me!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button onclick="myfunc()"></button>
Name: <input ng-model="name">
</div>
<script>
function myfunc(){
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
});
}
</script>
<p>Use the ng-model directive to bind the value of the input field to a property made in the controller.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: lazy loading controllers and content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168593/angularjs-lazy-loading-controllers-and-content)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not the best way to solve this problem. The user should use the `ng-click` directive to invoke a function that loads the ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onclick` to load a controller, use the `ng-click` directive to invoke a function that loads the `ng-model`.

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myfunc = function() {
        $scope.name = "John Doe";
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button ng-click="myfunc()">Load</button>
        Name: <input ng-model="name">
        <br>name={{name}}
</body>
```