# Use RequireJS to lazy load AngularJS DI components

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, requirejs, lazy-loading

I have a question about lazy loading services and factories. I've been researching this for over a week now and haven't found a satisfactory answer. I have found: [Lazy loading AngularJS modules with RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134023/lazy-loading-angularjs-modules-with-requirejs) which seems to come close but it's not what I'm looking for, I do not want to lazy-load my modules.

I do not know how to rig up a plunker using AngularJS and RequireJS to clarify my needs; so I will try and explain my needs as clearly as possible:

At this point in time each of my AngularJS controllers, services and factories looks like this:

```
var dependencies = ['something', 'something/else'];
define(dependencies, function() {

    var controller = function(something, else) {};
    angular.module('app').controller('myController', ['something', 'else', controller]);

});
```

This works. I load my dependencies using RequireJS and everything is alright. What is bothering me is the need to declare my dependencies and wrap my AngularJS code within a RequireJS define call, I would like AngularJS to (excuse me here) do the right thing.

In theory the constructor of my controller is executed if and only if all the parameters which are promises are resolved. I would like to create a service resolver which returns a service promise for `something` and `something else` so that I can skip the dependencies within the RequireJS `define` call and handle that inside of my service resolver or even better inside of my DI container.

My question is this, does anyone have a solution for this pattern? Does anyone know of a way to change the way services and factories are loaded to promises? Or should I just implement it the way I've been doing and wait for AngularJS 2.0 and the child injectors?

I hope this question makes sense. Thank you for your time and help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to change the implementation. AngularJS does not have a set way to change the ServiceProvider to return custom promisses instead of concrete objects.

This will be possible in the future of AngularJS as [Vojta Jina](https://github.com/vojtajina) explains in [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OGGsf1ZXMs).