# how to force compile just lazy-loaded directivev

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have a directive constructor without any template and I'm passing an options througth the attributes to my factory which understand which dependencies it has.(I'm using require js  to load components, I wrapped the require function with promise which I'm getting from diretive)After resolve I put the templates(all they are directives) into constructor directive elem.html and $compile its contents() but the directives are not compiled they are just strings.What can I do force compile them(P.S. the directives are compiled after the ui-router's change)

Comment: I think this question is duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134023/lazy-loading-angularjs-modules-with-requirejs?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for response. I've passed this issue by setting the directives loading with Promise as a router resolver.
But the original issue was that I was needed to destroy the directives created scope and than force compile it again, as router does.